# How to make the size of a Button equal to the size of its parent Grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, layout

I have a button inside my grid. The thing is, the button is not so big as it contains only a textblock with a font size of 24.

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}"
    Command="{Binding Path=GetCertificateCommand}"
    Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Path=Width}"
    Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}, Path=Height}">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ForegroundSectionTitleStyle}" Text="Выбрать сертификат для подписи" />
</Button>
```

So, this size, which I get from the textblock, is not enough as I want the button to be much larger.

I decided to put it inside a `Grid` and then set the `Width` and `Height` of the button via `RelativeSource`. Actually, even if I assign those values to this Binding, it does nothing.

Of course I can set `Vertical/HorizontalAlignment` of Button to `Stretch` and `Center` to the `TextBlock` inside it, but I wonder why the explicit `RelativeSource` assignment is not working?

Comment: In WPF, you generally should avoid setting controls' sizes manually. Can you provide a screenshot how do you want your button to look like?

Comment: I wonder if your `TransparentStyle` is doing anything with the size of the button?

Comment: If you want to go the `RelativeSource` way, use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties instead. But as I mentioned before, this should be avoided.

Comment: @dymanoid so you want to say that the solution that I've proposed in my question is optimal and I should not even think about settings those properties at all as it goes against the WPF layout system?

Comment: The solution you proposed is bad because you set the width and height manually. Having that overwhelms the WPF automatic layout engine and goes against the WPF paradigm of dynamic user interface. If you really need some size constraints, use `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` properties, but not the `Width` and `Height`.